Seemingly incorrect definition of weak convergence in McCleary "A user's guide to ...".
On p.62 of McCleary's "A user's guide to spectral sequences" the following definition

A filtration $F$ of a differential graded module, $(A, d),$ is said to be weakly convergent if, for all $p,$ $Z^p_\infty = \cap_r Z_r^p,$ that is, if $F^p\cap \ker d = \cap_r(F^p A \cap d^{-1}(F^{p+r}A)).$

is provided with clarification

simple conditions on the filtration imply that it is weakly convergent ... 2) $\cap_p F^pA=\{0\}.$

Convergence assumes that $E_\infty$ equal to graded module of the limit and then the following theorem is claimed (seemingly incorrect)

Theorem 3.2. Let $(A, d, F)$ be a filtered differential graded module such that the filtration
is exhaustive and weakly convergent. Then the associated spectral sequence with $E_1^{p,q} \simeq H^{p+q}(F^p
A/F^{p+1}A)$ converges to $H(A, d),$ that is,
$$
  E_\infty^{p,q}\simeq F^pH^{p+q}(A, d)/F^{p+1}H^{p+q}(A, d).
$$

Definitions from McCleary can be compared to definitions from Boardman "Conditionally convergent spectral sequences" (same as of Cartan and Eilenberg). "Weak convergence (Cartan-Eilenberg)" corresponds to "convergence (McCleary) + exhaustiveness."
Boardman provides weaker statement compared to theorem 3.2:

If the filtration of $A$ by the subcomplexes $F^sC$ exhausts $A$ and is complete Hausdorff,
then the spectral sequence resulting from sequence $F^{s+1}A\hookrightarrow F^sA\rightarrowtail
F^sC/F^{s+1}A$ is
$$
  E^s_1 = H(F^sA/F^{s+1}A) \Rightarrow_s H(A),
$$
and it converges conditionally to the $H(A)=\mathrm{colim}_s H(F^sA).$

Later on p.63 of "A user's guide...", the statement (proposition 3.3, weak convergence equivalent definitions) is consistent with the definition of Cartan-Eilenberg (so the proof seems to contain error).
Question: Is the theorem 3.2 in McCleary re. convergence incorrect?
Update
The definition in the book should be in terms of $E_1$-sheet (as opposed to original definition on $E_0$-sheet) on exact couple (any derived exact couple can be also used)
$$
  H(F^s)\xrightarrow{i} H(F^{s+1})\xrightarrow{j}H(F^s/F^{s+1})
$$

A filtration $F$ of a differential graded module, $(A, d),$ is said to be weakly convergent if, for all $p,$ $\ker k = \mathcal{Z}^p_\infty = \cap_r \mathcal{Z}_r^p,$ that is, if $(\ker k)^p = \cap_r k^{-1}(\mathrm{im} i^r).$

$k$ is connecting morphism. One can prove Theorem 3.2 with adjusted definition using proof of Lemma 5.6 from Boardman:
$$ 
  \frac{\mathrm{im} j}{\mathcal{B}^s_\infty}\hookrightarrow\frac{\mathcal{Z}^s_\infty}{\mathcal{B}^s_\infty}
    \rightarrowtail\frac{\mathcal{Z}^s_\infty}{\ker k}
$$
Note
$$
    \frac{\mathrm{im} j}{\mathcal{B}^s_\infty}\xleftarrow{\approx j}
    \frac{H(F^sA)}{\mathrm{im} i + \ker[\eta^s:H(F^sA)\to H(A)]}
    \xleftarrow{\approx \eta^s}
    \frac{F^sH(A)}{F^{s+1}H(A)}
$$
Thank you.

I remember also getting massively tripped up by this issue. The statement in McCleary should be correct, but the notion of convergence actually does not correspond to any standard notation of convergence! This is because the notation $E^p_{\infty}$ actually means different things in either context. Let me denote what McCleary calls $Z^p_r$ by $M^p_r$. Then, what McCleary calls $B^p_r$ is simply $dM^{p-r}_r$, and $E^p_{\infty}=\bigcap_rZ^p_r/\bigcup_rB^p_r$.
Now, recall that for any spectral sequence $E^{\bullet,\bullet}_{\bullet}$, the usual definition of these modules is as subobjects
$$\dotsc\subseteq B^p_r\subseteq B^p_{r+1}\subseteq\dotsc\subseteq Z^p_{r+1}\subseteq Z^p_r\subseteq\dotsc\subseteq E^p_1,$$
inductively determined so that $Z^p_r/B^p_r=E^p_r$. Then, similarly, we set $E^p_{\infty}=\bigcap_rZ^p_r/\bigcup_rB^p_r$. In the case of the spectral sequence arising from a filtered cochain complex, these submodules are are given by $Z^p_r=M^p_r/M^{p-1}_{r-1}$ and $B^p_r=dM^{p-r+1}_{r-1}/dM^{p-r+1}_r$. [This follows e.g. by the construction in Theorem 2.6 of McCleary.]
Now, let $\pi\colon F^pA\rightarrow F^pA/F^{p+1}A$ be the canonical projection. Then, $Z^p_r=\pi(M^p_r)$ and $B^p_r=\pi(dM^{p-r+1})$ (yes, there is an index offset), so this relates the cycle and boundary terms as stated in 3.1 to the usual notions. The crux now is that $\pi(\bigcap_rM^p_r)\subseteq\bigcap_rZ^p_r$ is generally not an equality, so you will get different modules. Theorem 3.2 does identify $F^pH^{p+q}/F^{p+1}H^{p+q}$ with a submodule $\pi(\bigcap_rM^p_r)/B^p_{\infty}$ of $E^p_{\infty}$ and the obstruction for this inclusion to be an equality is where derived limits enter the picture. In fact, this scenario is precisely the start of the exact sequence in Lemma 5.6 of Boardman's paper.

Regarding $\pi,$ Proposition 3.3 in the book has incorrect statement: "$M^r_p = F^pA\cap d^{-1}(F^{p+r}A)$ is isomorphic to the module of cycles in $F^pA/F^{p+r}A$."

@dsh Ah, good catch. That's indeed an error.
